# Copy current file to clipboard

Tags: vim, copy, clipboard

How do I copy the current file to clipboard? I am not looking to copy the file contents itself. I want to copy the file and attach it in a different application.

An example of my use case

1. Open file using FzF
2. Make edits and save
3. Shortcut to copy the actual file to clipboard.
4. Attach it to Outlook or in Teams.

How do I achieve #3?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this in gVim using:

:noremap cf :silent !powershell Set-Clipboard -Path %